# Node.JS garbage collection event? or --trace-gc to stderr?

Tags: garbage-collection, node.js, stderr

As a general practice, when I write scripts, log messages always go to stderr and data (status messages, results from an algorithm, whatever) goes to stdout.

I would like to get this sent to stderr. Can that be done?

I would be fine to use my own handler to some sort of `process.on('gc')` event if there is one. Is there one?

I am writing some code now where stdout is reserved for data and I have no choice but to turn off --trace-gc. I am using `memoryUsage()` as a second best thing, but it does not tell the usage right before and right after GC, it just tells you the usage whenever `memoryUsage()` happened to be called.

Comment: This is a very old post but I ran across it and there exists a package https://www.npmjs.com/package/gc-profiler that does exactly that.

Comment: @migg, That should be an answer. :-)

Comment: Yes I thought about that but because this is a very old post and it would be a very short answer.

Answer (score 4):

A quick check of the v8 source code (where the garbage collector lives - [node src dir]/deps/v8/src/heap.cc and platform-posix.cc) shows that garbage collection messages are printed to the console using the standard linux vprint() (from printf(3)) so I'm pretty sure you cannot trap them without patching the source code.